# Unable to start UDP GStreamer Pipeline via OpenCV and Aruco

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, aruco

I'm trying to use opencv via aruco to read an UDP-Stream via Network on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using OpenCV 3.1.0 and Gstreamer 1.2.4.
I changed the code of the "aruco_simple.cpp" Example file to accomplish that, by changing the parameter of the VideoCapturer constructor to the GStreamer Pipeline:

```
    string PIPELINE_DEF = "udpsrc uri=udp://192.168.71.50:49152 do-timestamp=true name=src blocksize=1316 closefd=false buffer-size=100 !" \
    "tsdemux !" \
    "queue !" \
    "avdec_h264 max-threads=0 !" \
    "videoconvert !" \
           "xvimagesink name=opencvsink"
    //"appsink !"
;
    aruco::CameraParameters CamParam;

    // read the input image
    cv::Mat InImage;
    // Open input and read image
    //VideoCapture vreader(argv[1]);
    VideoCapture vreader(PIPELINE_DEF);
```

Executing this I always get the following Error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /home/osboxes/Aruco/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 834
Exception :/home/osboxes/Aruco/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:834: error: (-2) GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
 in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer
```

I found this Bug here http://code.opencv.org/issues/3953
But the solution does not help me in my case.

If I start a GStreamer Pipeline directly (without aruco and opencv) in Python it works.

GStreamer was found by opencv according to the cmake output:

```
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 1.2.4)
--       video:                     YES (ver 1.2.4)
--       app:                       YES (ver 1.2.4)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 1.2.4)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.2.4)
```